# MDX : get members from a subselect (FILTER BY in MDX+)

Tags: iccube, mdx-query

I've got the following MDX statement:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[ist]  AS __get_time_member__
SELECT
// Measures
{[Measures].[ist],[Measures].[soll]} ON 0,
// Rows
FROM  [Finance]
FROM ( SELECT [Time].[Time].[month].&[2018-04-01] on 0 from [Finance]
```

or in MDX+

```
FILTERBY [Time].[Time].[month].&[2018-04-01]
```

How can I get in the calculated measure, [ist], the time member defined in the subselect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MDX+ you've a couple of functions that allow to get some informations from the slicer and the subselect :

- [ContextMember](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/ContextMember.php) - This works like currentMember including the slicer and subselect
- [GetFilterInfo(hierarchy)](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/GetFilterInfo.php) - extracts only from slicer and subselect

In your case you can use GetFilterInfo function with the hierarchy you're looking for.

I guess is just a question of playing around with these functions.

PS: We could easily add GetSlicerInfo and GetSubselectInfo if needed.